# Distribute a monetary amount over rows until it depletes

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, aggregate, apply

For a particular data frame I have it is needed to distribute a certain amount(POT) over my data frame. When that amount is depleted it should give back the remaining data frame without assigning a value. Input DF:

```
Accepted    Jackpot Commision   Rank
NO          2760.33 279.85      1
NO          2760.33 279.85      1
NO          2760.33 279.85      1
NO          2760.33 279.85      1
NO          2760.33 206.38      2
NO          2760.33 206.38      2
NO          2760.33 206.38      2
```

as you can see the DF has 4 columns but in reality is way bigger but these are the columns that matter. I want to change Accepted to Yes while depleting the Jackpot with Commission based on the Rank column.

So jackpot - commission (2760.33 - 279.85 = 2480.48) turns Accepted into Yes for all rows having Rank 1. Jackpot is now: 2480.48. So this is what we can use for Rank 2 and so on. Until we reach 0 and simple all Accepted stay on NO.

```
Accepted    Jackpot Commision   Rank
YES         2760.33 279.85      1
YES         2760.33 279.85      1
YES         2760.33 279.85      1
YES         2760.33 279.85      1
NO          2480.48 206.38      2
NO          2480.48 206.38      2
NO          2480.48 206.38      2
```

I tried many things like `By, (s)apply, for, aggregate` and way more but i did not manage to get the correct answer. Any help is appreciated.

Full test data frame:

```
dput(tst_df)
structure(list(Accepted = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NO", "YES"), class = "factor"), 
    Jackpot = c(2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 
    2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33, 2760.33), Commision = c(12.71, 
    12.71, 12.71, 27.52, 27.52, 27.52, 27.52, 27.52, 16.94, 16.94, 
    16.94, 31.51, 31.51, 31.51, 31.51, 31.51, 3.72, 3.72, 16.68, 
    16.68, 16.68, 14.46, 14.46, 132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 
    132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 
    132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 
    132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 132.13, 12.19, 12.19, 6.82, 6.82, 
    55.31, 55.31, 55.31, 55.31, 55.31, 55.31, 55.31, 13.01, 13.01, 
    155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 
    155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 
    155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 
    155.8, 155.8, 155.8, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 
    279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 
    279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 
    279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 
    279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 
    279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 279.85, 1.86, 6.2, 6.2, 36.96, 
    36.96, 36.96, 36.96, 36.96, 36.96, 36.96, 36.96, 36.96, 9.3, 
    6.45, 8.26, 10.16, 10.16, 10.16, 10.16, 6.61, 5.78, 6.2, 
    18.59, 18.59, 18.59, 84.24, 84.24, 84.24, 84.24, 84.24, 84.24, 
    84.24, 84.24, 84.24, 84.24, 84.24, 31.19, 31.19, 31.19, 31.19, 
    31.19, 31.19, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 
    167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 
    167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 
    167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 167.78, 1.24, 
    3.81, 3.81, 4.13, 17.67, 17.67, 17.67, 17.67, 106.72, 106.72, 
    106.72, 106.72, 106.72, 106.72, 106.72, 106.72, 106.72, 106.72, 
    106.72, 106.72, 106.72, 106.72, 106.72, 106.72, 106.72, 9.3, 
    55.43, 55.43, 55.43, 55.43, 55.43, 55.43, 55.43, 2.23, 24.79, 
    24.79, 24.79, 24.79, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 
    260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 
    260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 
    260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 260.22, 
    260.22, 260.22, 3.51, 3.51, 3.51, 7.44, 4.29, 4.29, 6.61, 
    27.58, 27.58, 27.58, 27.58, 27.58, 27.58, 27.58, 115.08, 
    115.08, 115.08, 115.08, 115.08, 115.08, 115.08, 115.08, 115.08, 
    115.08, 115.08, 115.08, 115.08, 115.08, 115.08, 115.08, 206.38, 
    206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 
    206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 
    206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 
    206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 
    206.38, 206.38, 206.38, 69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 
    69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 4.63, 0, 6.69, 
    6.69, 6.69, 6.69, 66.85, 66.85, 66.85, 66.85, 66.85, 66.85, 
    66.85, 66.85, 66.85, 11.98), Rank = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
    33L, 33L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 23L, 23L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 38L, 38L, 58L, 58L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 70L, 70L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 22L, 47L, 47L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 85L, 53L, 60L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 34L, 48L, 54L, 
    41L, 41L, 41L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 42L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 21L, 
    21L, 21L, 21L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 30L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 79L, 45L, 
    45L, 46L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 104L, 26L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 57L)), .Names = c("Accepted", "Jackpot", 
"Commision", "Rank"), row.names = c(NA, -367L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can I delete duplicates?

Comment: Nope thats the problem. Each row is a transaction so i cant remove it. Thats the down side. In this example i did not show transaction ID.

Comment: I'm thinking about a while loop, but there must be a better way to do that.

Comment: Based on your data, it seems like all the Accepted will be YES, i.e. the amount isn't depleted in this dataset.  Is this right? There's no need for a loop; `cumsum` is part of the solution.

Comment: @WeihuangWong That is exactly the case. But if you take the example data, it might be we run out of Jackpot (in this case its not because the sum off all commision is 2178. If this is not the case simply all rows will be accepted when the jackpot is 0 all other rows should stay no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this dataset, it appears that the "Jackpot" isn't depleted, so the solution is trivial. That is,

```
library(dplyr)
tst_df %>%
  distinct() %>%
  arrange(Rank) %>%
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(Commision), remaining = Jackpot - cumsum) 
#    Accepted Jackpot Commision Rank  cumsum remaining
# 1        NO 2760.33    279.85    1  279.85   2480.48
# 2        NO 2760.33    206.38    2  486.23   2274.10
# 3        NO 2760.33    155.80    3  642.03   2118.30
# 4        NO 2760.33    132.13    4  774.16   1986.17
# <snip>
# 48       NO 2760.33     13.01   70 2172.54    587.79
# 49       NO 2760.33      7.44   79 2179.98    580.35
# 50       NO 2760.33      9.30   85 2189.28    571.05
# 51       NO 2760.33      4.63  104 2193.91    566.42
```

Suppose we set the "Jackpot" to a smaller number. The solution is to figure out the `Rank` at which the amount is depleted, then join the summary table to the original dataset:

```
new_df <- mutate(tst_df, Jackpot = 1000)
accepted <- new_df %>%
  distinct() %>%
  arrange(Rank) %>%
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(Commision),
         remaining = Jackpot - cumsum,
         Accepted = if_else(remaining > 0, "YES", "NO")) 
head(accepted)
#   Accepted Jackpot Commision Rank  cumsum remaining
# 1      YES    1000    279.85    1  279.85    720.15
# 2      YES    1000    206.38    2  486.23    513.77
# 3      YES    1000    155.80    3  642.03    357.97
# 4      YES    1000    132.13    4  774.16    225.84
# 5       NO    1000    260.22    5 1034.38    -34.38
# 6       NO    1000    115.08    6 1149.46   -149.46
```

So here all the `Rank`s of 4 or below have `Accepted` equal to "YES". Finally

```
out <- left_join(select(accepted, Accepted, Rank), select(tst_df, -Accepted))
```

Comment: Looks really nice. I cant test right now (not behind my laptop). When it works i accept it tomorrow! Thanks.